# Data not updating before view is presented SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Here is the button where I am calling my load data function and presenting the new view with my data that is supposed to be loading on button click.

```
Button(recentModel.dateTime) {
                loadData(dT: recentModel.dateTime) {
                    self.showingView.toggle()
                }
            }.font(.custom("Gill Sans", size: 12)).padding(.vertical, 1).sheet(isPresented: $showingView)
            {
                    View(lPSelections: lP, tSelections: t, mSelections: m, b: Title)
            }
```

Here is my load data function. I am not sure what I need to do to fix that but basically the data that I am loading in here needs to be passed to the view that I call on that button click... yet the data is empty every time I load the view.

```
func loadData(dT : String, finished: () -> Void) {
    let urlString = "https://myurl" + dT
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        data, _, error in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        var result: Simulation?
        do {
            result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Simulation.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed : \(error)")
        }
        
        guard let final = result else {
            return
        }
        
        let t = f
        
        for ts in t {
            lP.append(ts.lP!)
            m.append(ts.m!)
            t.append(ts.t!)
        }
        
        print("--------------------------------------------------")
        print(lP)
        
        
    })
    
    finished()

    task.resume()
    
    
}
```

And at the end, I print the lP and that is done so I know the data is being loaded it is just being loaded after that view is already done loading and being presented.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to call finished() inside the url completion handler.

Comment: Can you expand more on this? When I out finished() inside of the url completion handler, it gives me an error. Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'finished'

Comment: Added an answer with info on how to annotate it to fix that error.

Comment: This is SwiftUI. Please learn to use Publishers/Observers rather than completion handlers. And in UIKit and SwiftUI multiple arrays as ***source of truth*** are strongly discouraged.

Comment: @vadian can you please show this ?

Comment: Please watch/read the free [100 days of SwiftUI course](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100) by Paul Hudson. All important basics are described in small portions. It's worth it to understand the unfamiliar *semantics* of SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `finished()` from *inside* the completion handler -- otherwise, it will get called before the URL data task runs/completes.

```
func loadData(dT : String, finished: @escaping () -> Void) { //<-- Here
    let urlString = "https://myurl" + dT
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        data, _, error in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        //etc -- code omitted for brevity
        
        finished() //<-- Here
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

In general, I highly recommend moving asynchronous code like this into an `ObservableObject`.